# Is there a use for the rind after making Citrus Sugar?

Tags: culinary-uses, lemon, oranges, citrus

I have made Citrus Sugar and am now separating the lemon (and/or orange) rind from the sugar. Now I am wondering is there any use for the leftover citrus rind?

Comment: Does it have any flavor left or has the sugar absorbed most of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how fine you have shaved the rind/zest, you can consider candying it (boil it in syrup till it become very transparent) or dip it in chocolate after candying it. if it is too fine, then add it into your next chocolate recipe to get orange-flavoured chocolate....

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fine grating - Lemon Drop shots: coat the lip of the shot glass